# Is there a name or use for this vector subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

A pretty easy review question for an upcoming course in linear vector spaces is the following:

> Let $A, B \in \mathbb{C}^{p\times p}$ be Hermitian. Show that $AB = BA \iff(AB)^H = AB$

Or, plainly, that $AB$ is Hermitian if and only if $A$ and $B$ commute.

This question got me thinking about the following set:

> Let $B \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times q}$ such that $p \geq q$ and $rank(B) = q$
> Define $\mathcal{A} :=\{A\in \mathbb{R}^{p\times q}:A^TB=B^TA\}$

It's pretty easy to show that this is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{p\times q}$:

> The matrix of all zeros in $\mathbb{R}^{p\times q}$ is in $\mathcal{A}$ as $0_{p\times q}^TB=0_{q\times q}$ is symmetric
> $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under linear combinations:
> Let $A_{1}, A_{2} \in \mathcal{A}$ and $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$
> Then $(\alpha A_{1} + \beta A_{2})^TB=\alpha A_{1}^TB + \beta A_{2}^TB \\ = \alpha B^TA_{1} + \beta B^TA_{2} = B^T(\alpha A_{1}) + B^T(\beta A_{2}) = B^T(\alpha A_{1} + \beta A_{2})$

So, if I didn't forget something, we're good! I played around with this a little and found the following properties of $\mathcal{A}$:

> $BA^TB = BB^TA$  $\forall A \in \mathcal{A}$
> $B, B^\dagger{^T} \in \mathcal{A}$
> $\forall A_{1}, A_{2} \in \mathcal{A}$ the following holds: $A_{2}B^TA_{1}B^TA_{2} \in \mathcal{A}$

And I think that the dimension of this subspace is $q(p - \frac{q-1}{2})$

Mostly I thought this set was a little neat, but it's not something I think I've explicitly come across in the past and any search combination I tried to come up with has been futile. I'm interested in whether this is actually a *thing* or just a thing. That is to say, is there a name for this subspace? Are there potential applications? I can see that, if $\mathcal{A}$ were restricted further to positive semi-definite matrices, then it would constitute a set of matrices that generate covariance-like matrices based on $B$, but I'm unsure if that is necessarily a vector space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the computation, you'll see that $\mathcal A$ is also closed under multiplication of operators and the transpose operation. We say that $\mathcal A$ is the commutant of $A$ in $B(\mathcal H)$, or, equivalently, the commutant of the polynomial subalgebra generated by $A$. This sort of commutator construction is very important in the world of von Neumann algebras, as can be seen by the von Neumann bicommutant theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_bicommutant_theorem.

Some careful management will show that, if you take this subalgebra $\mathcal A$ and take its commutant in a finite-dimensional space, you'll return the polynomial subalgebra generated by $A$.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for! Thanks for the response.